# pubDate not synced with timezone of the Wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, timezone, rss

I run a small WordPress site and we depend a lot on views from sites that pull our RSS feed. Previously, our articles appeared on top of their feed, but what happens recently is that now pubDate in my RSS feed is in timezone +0000, and my site and our partner sites are in GMT +2, so our posts appear in their RSS feed like they are published 2 hours ago and not now. Timezone in WordPress site is set with city in GMT +2, I tried putting cities with GMT +4 but it didn't help. Any ideas how to manipulate pubDate to be in sync with timezone set in WordPress admin panel?
For the reference, feed is [byte.com.hr/feed](http://byte.com.hr/feed/)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot manipulate the pubDate's timezone of the WordPress feed, instead, you need to set the correct locale for your site:

> WordPress adheres to the RSS specifications. This means that **the time
> and date format will NOT use your blog time/date format as set in your
> settings**, instead it uses the time and date format from the RFC822
> specification. This looks for example like this: Sun, 06 Sep 2009
> 16:10:34 **+0000**
>
> Note: The time/date format of feed should NOT be localized since the
> the current RSS specifications are referring to RFC822 specification
> which specifies English as a default. **This implies that every RSS
> consumer should take care of translating time/date according to its
> locale.**

Source: [WordPress Feeds docs](https://wordpress.org/support/article/wordpress-feeds/#rss-feed-time-and-date-format)

The locale is in your case `en-US`, but it should be the one for Crotia - `hr`, I assume?

```
<language>en-US</language>
```

Comment: to set different languages in backend and frontend, see here: https://optimizerwp.com/change-wordpress-language/ (last paragraph) / WP docs: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/locale

Comment: btw: you should absolutely change the language code of your site as it is in Croatian, but you are telling browsers and search engines etc, that it is in US English! see your site's code: <html lang="en-US">

Comment: Hey, thank you for your response, but unfortunatelly changing site language did not help :( Any other ideas?

Comment: it is now correct: <language>hr</language>. Would you please share where exactly you see that the publication date is shown wrong? (add screenshot or link to your question)

Comment: I tried your corrected feed here: https://www.feed-reader.net/. It displays the pub date of the google pixel article as 05.08.2020 11:30:44, while your feed item says 05 Aug 2020 09:30:44. This looks correct to me - the feed reader uses the hr locale to shift the pub date from UTC0 to GMT2.